# How to unit test a TextOutputFormatter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I've written a `TextOutputFormatter` that's working as expected, but now I want to put a few unit tests around it. The first parameter to `WriteResponseBodyAsync` is an `OutputFromatterWriteContext` that I'm not sure how to instantiate.

I tried to use the following, but the `context.HttpContext.Response.Body` ends up being a null stream.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldPrefixAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var output = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var context = new OutputFormatterWriteContext(
        new DefaultHttpContext(),
        (stream, encoding) => new HttpResponseStreamWriter(stream, encoding),
        typeof(string),
        output
    ) {
        ContentType = "application/json"
    };

    // Act
    var filter = new XssJsonOutputFormatter();
    await filter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, Encoding.UTF8);

    using var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
    var json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var wanted = $"{XssJsonOutputFormatter.XssPrefix}{output}";

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(wanted, json);
}
```

Comment: You failed because the responsebody could not be read

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Right, that's why I said the response body was null.  What I'm asking is what I'm supposed to do to enable it.

Comment: I think you could replace the default responsebody with  memorystream

Answer (score 2):

the responsebody could not be read
[image]
I think you could try to replace the default body with memorystream which could be read in Unit Test

```
var httpcontext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpcontext.Response.Body = new MemoryStream();
```